# Measure distance between objects in picture with python

Tags: python, image, processing, measurement

I have a picture with squares represented as numpy array. The squares are variable in width and  horizontal position but colors are fixed. How would I calculate width and distance between those (blue) squares in python?

[image: squares]

numpy_array`[1]` contains image array:
`[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1 195 196 202 204 207
 203 201 216 219 223 228 233 235 237 239 236 235 233 233 233 232 232 234
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240
 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 239 241 239
 240 239 241   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
   1   4   1   1   2  87  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  93  47   1   2   0
   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199
 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199 199]`

Comment: Edge to edge distance? What is inside `numpy_array[1]`?

Comment: Right edge of left blue square to left edge of the right blue square, or in other words the width of the first red square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of the boundaries of your squares (which aren't square...) with

```
>>> da = np.where(np.abs(np.diff(a)) > 100)
>>> da
(array([120, 254, 375]),)
```

from which you can calculate the distances and widths that you need, perhaps by:

```
>>> da = np.insert(da, 0,0)
>>> da = np.append(da, len(a))
>>> np.diff(da)
array([120, 134, 121, 165])
```

If your data is noisy (as it seems to be), you might need to tweak the threshold, `100`. If I understand you, `a` is the same as `numpy_array[1]` in your question: you might consider summing or averaging rows to remove some of the noise.